# ASP.NET Select RadioButtonList value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but with now luck.  Was hoping you can help me.  here is my script:

```
function confirmPurge() {
        var d = confirm("You are about to purge all records, click Ok to proceed");
        if (d) {
            var c = document.getElementByName("yes");
            c.checked = true;
        }
        else {
            var c = document.getElementByName("no");
            c.checked = true;
        }
```

and html is this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPurgeRecords" runat="server" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem onclick="confirmPurge();" name="yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" name="no">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

When I try to run it, i get a pop up asking me to click ok or cancel.  If I click ok my code breaks and I get this error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ScriptManager' is undefined"

Was wondering why is this not working? or is there a better way to programatically set which button in radio list is selected.

Comment: I'd say you're mixing things `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is server side code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to if user click ok, set radiobutton list selected value yes.  If they click cancel for it to be no.  I was following example from this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1489039.aspx/1

Comment: I've updated to code to show a new example I tried, same results though.  It says the that object doesn't exist or null.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also facing same problem but fortunately found one solution. Code for the same is below

```
function test() {
var rad = document.getElementById('<%=rblPurgeRecordse.ClientID %>');
var radio = rad.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
       if (radio[i].checked)
       {
           //your Code goes here....
           alert("SelectedValue = " + radio[i].value);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the value of the actual radiobutton not the list item. And remember that the ID of the radiubotton you assign in the .NET control isn't the actual ID on the rendered page so you'll need to use the ClientID.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('<% rblPurgeRecords.ClientID %>');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        // the value of the radio button is : radios[i].value);

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try just adding the first line of your code, my IDE complains and wont let me run the page, I got 7 errors in total and here is the first one: Error 2 Invalid expression term '.' c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\meterreadgenerator\738a4d39\194cec92\App_Web_0m1pm0od.0.cs 642 17  ----  I have found similar solutions over the web, but they all always had this error, could not get past the first line of code that you have posted there.

Comment: This code doesn't work because `radios.length` is always `= 1`. `rbl` is being translated into table